# Detecting suspicious/bot IP addresses in big access log (~30Gb)

Tags: r, hadoop, bigdata

I have big access log (~30Gb) and I'm looking for ways for find suspicious/bot IP addresses. Of course, we can replace IP with (IP + User_Agent). So my questions are:

- find average requests number that are done from any IP
- find IP addresses that are making more requests than average (see previous point)
- find IP addresses that are doing requests regulary (every hour for example) during day
- you recommendations about how to detect bot

This log is rather big and I don't think that R lang could process it. Should I use some kind of storage behind R (hadoop or something similar)? I absolutely have no experience in processing/analyzing big data so any ideas, recommedations & tuts/articles are appreciated.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/vignettes/Overview.pdf - Note, 30gb of data depending on the width of the file, could take about an hour to load initially. So... set it and forget it if you're working on a weak machine or a laptop.

Comment: If you're worried about multiple requests you'll proabably see it just as equally in the first 1gb of the file as you would in the last 20gb... have you even tried loading up any of your data yet?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen thank you for `bigmemory` library tip - I will try it. About first 1Gb of data: you mean that analyzing 3% slice of data will show approximately the same results as whole 100% of data?

Comment: Sometimes, yes. But either way - always good to look at a sample. While you wait.

Comment: Start with sampling and perform some exploratory data analysis (basic counting/distributions). Summarize to ASNs. Divide into manageable chunks and give https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection a go with chunked samples. Take a look at [spark](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/anomaly-detection-with-apache-spark-2). Also, you prbly know _some_ good traffic sources. Filter those out to try to reduce the bulk.

Answer (score 0):

The access log probably contains a lot of data which you may not need based on your question, if you only care about the time of the request and the orginating IP you could easily reduce the data size by extracting "columns" from the input before reading it into R, some standard command line tools such as cut or awk should do the  trick. 
If you want to keep more details another option could be to load the access log into a database and use this for further processing, 30GB is not a lot for a database, but of course this means some additional work: design a datbase schema and a way to load the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following type of analysis

- Getting the geo location of IP addresses and comparing access frequency based on geo_location + time at geo_location (the access frequency could be normal during day time at the geo location but not after midnight)
- If you have username information, check whether multiple IP addresses are using the same username during same time period

WSO2 has done some Anomaly Detection work using their Analytics Platform which is pretty scalable for most anomaly detection scenarios. Check it out - http://wso2.com/analytics/solutions/fraud-and-anomaly-detection-solution/
This might be a better option than doing through R, since it allows you to do complex event processing (through SQL like queries) as well as machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following type of analysis

a) If the IP address is from data center range, it is likely from a bot than normal user.

b) If the IP address is from search engine range, it is high likely from a search engine bot.

You can get the geolocation database from [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com) which has the usage type information to detect data center or search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check goaccess.io - works for me. With logs for different websites, distributed on several servers. Allows usage of GEOiP and identifies bots out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://ipdetective.io it tracks IP addresses that originate from datacenters, vpns, proxies, tor node and bot nets. It offers a free API as well so you can test it out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32685184)